# Sort a text file by numeric value of the last word on each line

Tags: bash

I have a file.txt with this text:

```
hello my name is John:  4  
hello my name is Loi:  23 
hello my name is Joi: 45
hello my name is Jordan: 476 
hello my name is Manu: 98
```

I want to order this file to echo it later and i want it to be like this:

```
hello my name is Jordan: 476 
hello my name is Manu: 98
hello my name is Joi: 45
hello my name is Loi:  23 
hello my name is John:  4
```

How can I do it? I know that ita can be done with sort -n but i need it the other way around and the problem is that it has text.. . Thanks
(the numbers of the file are on different lines)

Comment: It does not work. it does not order the values :(

Comment: Is that for just this especific example? I have other file like this with different numbers and it shows a part of the text cut only, i need something that works for every file. Thanks

Comment: The question is not clear enough; do you have other columns in the file ?

Comment: What is "blablah"? Is it a fixed number of fields? You say "does not work" several times, but if you provide a more realistic example, you'll get better answers

Comment: yes for example line1: hello my name is YTY:  259  line2: hello my name is NDH:  123 line3: hello my name is YRY:  458 line3: hello my name is YTV:  44

Comment: Edit your question

Comment: blablabla is a random text

Comment: No, I have edited the post to make it clearer I only want to order the lines in order by their number

Comment: If `Hello my name is` is a fixed number of columns, then `sort` itself can just be told to use the fifth column only and ignore all others. Whereas if your input needs to be sorted on the _last_ word and there's no consistency to the number of words before it, that's an important constraint for the question's sample data to reflect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reverse the file, you can then sort from the numbers and reverse back

```
$ sed 's/[^0-9]*\(.*\)/\1 &/' input_file | sort -rn | sed 's/[^a-z]*\(.*\)/\1/'
blabla 45
blabla 23
blabla 12
blabla 5
blabla 4
```

Comment: HMMM I thought it worked with this but i tried other values and it does not

Comment: @Tenko Does this work? `sed 's/[^0-9]*\(.*\)/\1 &/' input_file | sort -rn | sed 's/[^a-z]*\(.*\)/\1/'`

Comment: This is assuming that the only digits on the line are in the last field. I'd do it the other way: `sed -E 's/^.*([[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]*$/\1 &/'`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ["decorate-sort-undecorate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) pattern here:

```sh
awk '{print $NF "\t" $0}' file.txt | sort -nr -k1,1 | cut -f 2-
```

Comment: This also works <3

Comment: @Tenko, not only it works but it's also more robust than the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

sort has a "key" argument that lets you specify which "field" to sort on.  I'm not sure this will work on all versions...in all shells...but it's great for one-offs when you just want the answer.

```
sort -n -k 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with only one sort command:

```
sort -t : -n -r -k2 file.txt
```

this command segments each line by colon (-t :) and order by second field (-k2) in reverse mode (-r).